# Cordova build command failed

Tags: eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

Running command "cordova build" on command prompt result in built failed. Found underneath the error sample.  Can someone help me for a quick fix. The aim is to run my first phonegap android hello world project but am stuck with this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that this is not phonegap error but android error. Did you try to make hello world in android first?

Comment: no unable to create class inside the main project package

Comment: please check second image

Comment: re-install your android SDK, and try to give it a folder name without () and spaces. You should be able to make platform hello world application before trying phonegap hello world.

Comment: re-installed but error persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

Download ant for windows, http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi. Extract and place it somewhere in your computuer.

Open your CMD and type this command.

```
SET ANT_HOME=%PATH%;c:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin
```

Restart your computer.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/11/02/common-errors-during-developing-android-app-in-mac-linux-and-windows-platform/